Problem with Nginx proxy redirection to Svelte application hosted in Droplet together with Ghost CMS Local
I want to deploy a sveltekit app to an ubuntu virtual server (v 22.04.3 lts) with local Ghost CMS also runing locally, and using a nginx server proxy to redirect the main '/' to the application and '/blog' to Ghost.
So far the virtual server comes with Ghost CMS already installed and i´ve already configured it, it runs automatically and I´ve set the url to the ipaddress/blog and it works great. However when I set the proxy redirection to the localhost of the sveltekit application it doesn´t work.
Here is the nginx site configuration for the svelte app:
upstream sveltekit-server {
  server localhost:port;
  keepalive 8;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server_ip;

  root /var/www/svelte_app/build/client;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @sveltekit;
  }

  location @sveltekit {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;

    proxy_pass http://sveltekit-server;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # error_page 502 = @static;
  }

  location ^~ /_app/immutable/ {
    # gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    access_log off;
    try_files $uri $uri/;
  }
}

here is the ghost cms site conf:
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name server_ip;
    root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification 

    location /blog {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}```

  

I´ve tried changind localhost ports, changing to multiple nginx site configuration taken from various sites on the problem, so far nothing has worked. Perhaps it is the nginx configuration or I´ve to reinstall nginx.

If someone identifies the problem it will be appreciated.

